# initial_data.json not loading before tests

Tags: django, testing, nose

I am using `django_nose` to run my tests. I have a fixture `initial_data.json` which is an app's folder : `my_app/fixtures/initial.json`.

The fixture loads fine when using `python manage.py syncdb`, but doesn't load at all when running the tests `python manage.py test my_app` (while I guess it should load !?). Any pointer to what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#fixture-loading):

> Once you've created a fixture and placed it in a fixtures directory in one of your INSTALLED_APPS, you can use it in your unit tests by specifying a fixtures class attribute on your django.test.TestCase subclass:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Animal

class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']

    def setUp(self):
        # Test definitions as before.
        call_setup_methods()

    def testFluffyAnimals(self):
        # A test that uses the fixtures.
        call_some_test_code()
```

Comment: It works !!! Thanks so much ! I am pretty sure that in previous Django versions <= 1.3 ? `initial_data.json` used to be loaded automatically ... Also, beware of not using `django.utils.unittest.TestCase`, this doesn't seem to import fixtures

Comment: thanks, it was definitely not intuitive to me that the test suite wouldn't use the fixture automatically.   Doesn't the test suite do a syncdb too, so you'd expect it to load initial_data?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms but a different solution.  I am running my tests through `py.test` instead of `manage.py test`.

In `appname/fixtures` I had `initial_data.json` and `foo.json`.  My test looked like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestFoo(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['initial_data.json', 'foo.json']

    ...
```

However, when I ran the test `initial_data.json` was not being loaded, but `foo.json` was.

For me, the solution was to rename `initial_data.json` to `base.json`, and then the fixture was loaded.

I don't think this is the original poster's problem, but posting this so the next person that has the same problem as me can find something. :)